# Why do room database creations only need to synchronize `Room.databaseBuilder.build`?

Tags: android, android-room, synchronized

I'm following the [Android Room with a View - Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#6) code lab and I came across the following code:

```
companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time. 
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): WordRoomDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java, 
                        "word_database"
                    ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
   }
```

For the most part, this makes sense. However, I'm a little confused by the synchronization part. Technically, couldn't two threads call `getDatabase` at the same time, and both of them get past the `if` statement and then each create their own database handles? I would think all of the code in `getDatabase` needs to be protected by the mutex. Why does only the creation part need to be protected by a mutex?

Comment: I agree, this code doesn't seem safe. Besides, this should get wired up by your dependency inversion framework. :-)

Comment: cool. opened an issue here then in that case. Looks like it might be a problem with the auto-translation from java to kotlin. https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/issues/58

Comment: This is my question too!